# Why do some cryptocurrency trading platforms require users to use the platform's native crypto token to access the platform?

Tags: trading, cryptocurrency

I read on [CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/11/11/ftx-ceo-sam-bankman-fried-lost-billionaire-status-filed-bankruptcy.html):

> FTT, the native crypto token that gives users access to the FTX trading platform.

Why do some cryptocurrency trading platforms require users to use the platform's native crypto token to access the platform?

Answer (score 4):

I refer you to Sam Bankman-Fried's [interview](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-04-25/sam-bankman-fried-described-yield-farming-and-left-matt-levine-stunned) with the [Odd Lots Podcast](https://www.bloomberg.com/oddlots-podcast). You need *some* gimmick to pull in the rubes.

Note: FTX doesn't *require* users to use their token, but they give discounts on fees to those users who do.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why platforms might require users to use their native crypto tokens. One reason is that it can help to create a more seamless experience for users. For example, if a platform requires users to use its native token to access the platform, the platform can more easily keep track of user activity and make sure that users are adhering to the platform's rules and regulations. Additionally, using a platform's native token can help to create a more loyal user base, as users who hold the token may be more likely to use the platform regularly and to recommend the platform to others.